# Powershell Mysql Error

Tags: c#, mysql, powershell

This code is:

```
$cm = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql = "Select * FROM onaylanan Order by onaylanma_id ASC"
$cm.Connection = $Connection
$cm.CommandText = $sql
$dr = $cm.ExecuteReader()

while ($dr.Read())
{
$cm2 = New-Object -TypeName MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand
$sql2 = "Delete FROM onaylanan Where onaylanma_id=4"
$cm2.Connection = $Connection
$cm2.CommandText = $sql2
$dr2 = $cm2.ExecuteNonQuery()
  $dr2.Close();

}
$dr.Close();
$Connection.Close()
```

This Error is:

> Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error indicates, you can't execute two queries concurrently over the same connection.

Open a second connection (you could name it `Connection2`) and assign that to `$cm2`:

```
$cm2.Connection = $Connection2
```